# How to generate HASH for Django model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to generate unique HASH values for my Django models of 10 digit i have tried these methods but i am getting this error

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column hash_3 is not unique
```

Here what i have tried :

```
import os
import time
import hashlib
from os import path
from binascii import hexlify
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

def _createHash():
    """This function generate 10 character long hash"""
    hash = hashlib.sha1()
    hash.update(str(time.time()))
    return  hash.hexdigest()[:-10]


class tags(models.Model):
    """ This is the tag model """

    seo_url1 = models.URLField()
    seo_url2 = models.URLField()
    seo_url3 = models.URLField()
    tagDescription = models.TextField()                 # Tag Description
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)              # Tag name
    tagSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)          # Extra info can be added to the existing tag using this field
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)     # Time at which tag is updated
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # Time at which tag is created
    hash_1 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=_createHash(),unique=True)
    hash_2 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=_createHash(),unique=True)
    hash_3 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=_createHash(),unique=True)
```

I have also tried this method:

```
def _createHash():
    """This function generate 10 character long hash"""
    return hexlify(os.urandom(5))
```

I have a script which inserts data into this model every time i run my script i got above mentioned error ..is there any other way of doing this..i want to store unique hash values into columns `hash_1,hash_2,hash_3`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't call the `_createHash()` function in your field, but just pass the reference to the callable in your model, e.g.

```
hash_1 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=_createHash,unique=True)
```

As Lennart Regebro mentioned in his answer, you'll get the same value for each time you start the server in your attempt.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) say this about it:

> Field.default
>
> The default value for the field. This can be a value or
>   a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new
>   object is created.

Comment: You are right out of curiosity but if i want to pass parameter to the method `_createHash()` then how do i do that.....

Comment: for instance i have a method `def _generateSEOURL(pattern,StringToconcatenate):
    return  pattern + StringToconcatenate`  and i want to pass `seo_url1 = models.URLField(default=_generateSEOURL("discounts-in-",tag))` parameters like this ...to concatenate some string to every tag value then how do i do that...

Comment: You may have to just create a wrapper function which contains the parameters you would want to pass...

`def _createHashForModel(): return _createHash(10)` and then `default=_createHashForModel`

Answer (score 5):

`_createHash()` is called when you define the model, so you have the same default every time you create a new object.

You can look at creating the hash in the `save()` method of the model, that's probably the easiest.

Comment: Hi @Lennart_Regebro, how can we use it inside the `save()` method?