# Django Session counter

Tags: django

I'm making a food order project in Django, and I want to set unique order numbers for quick verification of the user when they come to pick the food up after the order.

If I create a random combination of numbers and letters, there can be an issue of two orders having the same order number. Is it possible to make the order number unique to each session?

Answer (score 1):

Just use normal incremental order numbers and One Time Passwords(OTP)

User [pyotp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyotp) to generate random OTP for order.

When user orders, create a secret string. Then Generate an OTP for user and send it to them.

When they arrive to pick up, they show the OTP. You can check it using `pyotp` and the secret string to verify.

Use counter based OTP.

Store the secret key in the order model.

Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing this on the `request.session` or is it a model in the database? If it's the model in the database that's a lot simpler. Just set the `unique=True` kwarg in the field. Though you still have to generate the unique fields.

Look at [this guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853815/how-to-generate-hash-for-django-model) `_createHash` function in his question. Combined with the accepted answer you can create unique order ID's this way. If it's just attached the the `request.session` object, it'll be more difficult(if not impossible) to be 100% sure that the string has not been repeated, because there's no way to query all the existing Sessions for a custom added attribute. I don't think `session` is the word you're looking for, though.